# How to send message from Microsoft Teams to a custom application or achieve cross platform communication

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to understand as what can be done in order to enable cross platform communication with Microsoft Teams. I've researched but there is nothing from Microsoft that talks on this subject or even didn't find anything on Google. However, this is what is possible with Facebook messenger. I've created an application which can communicate with FB messenger by means of `webhook`.
I've an API, which is configured in FB app (ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks#verification-requests). Microsoft does talk about `outgoing webhook`, but that's for BOT conversation not real time communication. Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Now there is [fluid framework](https://fluidframework.com/) from Microsoft that is probably what you are after. There is also a [sample](https://fluidframework.com/docs/recipes/teams/) how to go with it in teams

We are using our own backend though for real-time communications (based on web sockets). But thinking of migrating to this fluid thing.

Comment: Than you for showing the direction. I'll study the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Teams supports both incoming and outgoing webhooks, but the implementation is quite different - incoming webhooks are basically just an endpoint, but yes, outgoing webhooks work best with a bot behind the scenes. Another alternative though, especially if it's all in the same Microsoft 365 tenant (i.e. if you're not building an external app, like for the Store), then you can just use Power Automate/Flow to listen for messages, and then call your app. There's a cost to this kind of Flow, but you can also look at Azure Logic Apps (the engine Power Automate is built on).

Comment: @Hiton, thanks for the guidance. I'm building app in AWS.

Comment: ok. AWS is fine - the hosting isn't too much of an issue, rather the development model. You can build any of what you need, even in AWS. Even a Teams bot can be hosted there

Comment: I see that you are a Teams expert :)

Comment: lol - what does that even mean :-)

Comment: I checked your stackoverflow profile, says "Microsoft Teams & SharePoint Entrepreneur", hence.